# Using callback method type with rest parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

Parent:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const childCompCallBack = (accountUrl: string, ...params: string[]) => {
    console.log(accountUrl);
    console.log(...params);
    ...
  };
 return (
  ChildComponent setAccounts={childCompCallBack}
 )
};
```

---

Child:

```
export type queryParams = {
  setAccounts: (accountUrl: string, ...params: string[]) => void;
}

const ChildComponent = ({ setAccounts }: queryParams) => {
  setAccounts("https://xyz/", "drafts", "2")
};
```

I am having issues when trying to **use** the type `queryParams` in `childCompCallBack` argument. Currently my implementation works but I want to get rid of the implicit argument declaration in `childCompCallBack` and use the exported `queryParams` type from the child.
Any suggestions will be helpful.ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to `queryParams` within the parent file, you can simply make your variable of the child type:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const childCompCallBack: queryParams['setAccounts'] = (accountUrl, ...params) => {
    console.log(accountUrl);
    console.log(...params);
    ...
  };
 return (
  ChildComponent setAccounts={childCompCallBack}
 )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could break the types:

```
export type setAccounts = (accountUrl: string, ...params: string[]) => void

export type queryParams = {
  setAccounts : setAccounts
}
```

Then you can just use that:

```
const childCompCallBack : setAccounts = (accountUrl, ...params) => {
...
```